# javascript: click event is not triggered when dropdown is open

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

here is my html

```
  <div class="test">
            <div class="select">
              <select name="slct" id="slct">
                <option class="default_option" value="A">A</option>

                <option value="AAAA">AAAA</option>
                <option value="CNAME">CNAME</option>
                <option value="MX">MX</option>
                <option value="NS">NS</option>
                <option value="PTR">PTR</option>
                <option value="SOA">SOA</option>
                <option value="SRV">SRV</option>
                <option value="TXT">TXT</option>
                <option value="CAA">CAA</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I want to trigger an event when dropdown menu is opened.

so, I have written this jquery,

```
 $('.test').click(function () {
    // $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
    console.log('hello');
  });
```

But the problem is, the console is not printed when the dropdown is opened.
the console is printed when the dropdown is closed.

Comment: For me your code works well.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov I mean when I open the dropdown. I need to trigger an event. but in my current implementation, the event triggers when I click on the first option from dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are attaching the event before the DOM is fully loaded

You should attach the event inside `$(document).ready(function(){...`

**OR:** Use `.on()` which ensure that the event will be attached to the element that is added to DOM at a later time.

Also, if you want the code to be executed only when open you should use `focus`:

```
$('body').on('focus', '.test', function () {
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $('body').on('focus', '.test', function () {
    // $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
    console.log('hello');
  });
</script>

<div class="test">
  <div class="select">
    <select name="slct" id="slct">
      <option class="default_option" value="A">A</option>

      <option value="AAAA">AAAA</option>
      <option value="CNAME">CNAME</option>
      <option value="MX">MX</option>
      <option value="NS">NS</option>
      <option value="PTR">PTR</option>
      <option value="SOA">SOA</option>
      <option value="SRV">SRV</option>
      <option value="TXT">TXT</option>
      <option value="CAA">CAA</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the event is triggered, when I click on the dropdown options.

but, what I want is, immediately trigger the event, as soon as the dropdown is open

Comment: @Ashik, did you try `focus` event which I have mentioned in the updated answer?

Comment: yep.
it is fixed now.

what I have currently done is this: https://gist.github.com/ashiqdev/8e1ebefd1e3cf15c12b06e315bf434bb
but the problem is, when I focus again, event is not triggered

Comment: @Ashik, `focus` event works once, to make that work you lose the event by clicking else where and focus again:)

Comment: clicking elsewhere means? by writing code, click elsewhere? actually, when a focus event is triggered I apply a class so that the dropdown icon is changed. so, when user again clicks on the dropdown icon I need to apply the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a custom dropdown, not the `<select>` element